# Adding a node to an existing node while simultaneous manipulating it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to add or append a node to an parent node while at the same time manipulating that node being added.

I though this was possible:

```
//I though this was possible:
$('#master').after('<div id="test" style="border:solid 1px orange;"/>').text(1);
```

but the result updates the 'text' prop of the 'master' div while creating the other div under it.

I was able to achieve my goal using two calls:

```
$('#master').after('<div id="test" style="border:solid 1px orange;"/>');
$('#test').text(1);
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal in one shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mutation methods return the original element you called them on, not the thing you inserted.

You need to start from the new element:

```
$('<div id="test" style="border:solid 1px orange;"/>')
    .insertAfter('#master')
    .text(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
$('#master').after($('<div/>', {
    'id': 'test',
    'style': 'border:solid 1px orange;',
    'text': 1
}))
```

Or simply this

```
$('#master').after('<div id="test" style="border:solid 1px orange;">1</div>');
```